# Firebase Pub/Sub trigger function is called but event is null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I successfully publish to a topic:

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish my-topic --message '{"value":"data"}' --attribute value=myValue
```

and can succesfuly view the entry using the gcloud command:

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack my-subcription
```

I then created a firebase pubsub onPublish trigger function as follows:

```
exports.myfunction = functions.pubsub.topic('my-topic').onPublish(event => {

     const attributes = event.data.attributes;
     const message = event.data.json;

     const value= attributes['value'];
     const data = {
         key: value,
         key2: message.value
     };

     let ref= db.collection('devices').doc(value);

     return updateTheDataInMyFirestore(ref, data);
});
```

What i aim to do is update the data in my firestore to maintain real time data. The function is called but the event is always null and i get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined' when i try to access the attributes. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Please edit the question to demonstrate how exactly are you sending the message that gets received in this function, and what you expect the function to do as a result.  Also please be sure you're following the documentation for pubsub triggers. What you're showing now doesn't much match the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events

Comment: i have edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PubSub handler functions receive a first argument which is a [Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.pubsub.Message) type object.  (You're calling it `event`.)  According to the API docs that I linked to, the Message object has a property called `json`, which is the parsed JSON data from the payload of the message.

It looks like you're assuming that `data.attributes` in the Message contains the payload.  It doesn't.  Use the Message `json` property instead:

```
exports.myfunction = functions.pubsub.topic('my-topic').onPublish(message => {
    const payload = message.json
    console.log(payload)

    const value = payload.value

    // continue processing...
});
```

Comment: the link is down, updating is https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_pubsub_.message